# MacOS Sierra: I forgot my password but have the SSD's Filevault recovery key. Can I reset my password?

Tags: macos, password, recovery

I'm on MacOS Sierra. I forgot my password, but I have the SSD's FileVault recovery key. I used the "Recovery Key" account recovery method when I set up FileVault, so I can't use iCloud to unlock my account. Is there a way that I can reset my password and keep my data? Is there a way I can mount the drive and use the command line to reset only my account password and keychain?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [Support document by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860):

> ## Reset using your Recovery Key (FileVault must be on)
>
> If FileVault is turned on and you have a FileVault [Recovery Key](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204837), you can use that key to reset your password.
>
> 1. At the login screen, keep entering a password until you see a message saying that you can reset your password using your Recovery Key. If you don't see the message after three attempts, FileVault isn't on.
> 2. Click <kbd>></kbd>  next to the message. The password field changes to a Recovery Key field.
> 3. Enter your Recovery Key. Use uppercase characters, and include the hyphens.
> 4. Follow the onscreen instructions to create a new password, then click Reset Password when done.
> 5. Determine whether to [create a new login keychain](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860#keychain).
>
> If you can't log in with your new password after restarting your Mac, take these additional steps:
>
> 1. Restart again, then immediately hold down Command-R or one of the [other macOS Recovery key combinations](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204837) until you see the Apple logo or a spinning globe.
> 2. When you see the macOS Utilities window, choose Utilities > Terminal from the menu bar.
> 3. In the Terminal window, type `resetpassword, then press Return to open the Reset Password assistant pictured above.
> 4. Select ”My password doesn't work when logging in,” then click Next and follow the onscreen instructions for your user account.